# What is the purpose of ISAAC's randinit() function?

Tags: random-number-generator, isaac

I am a relative crypto noob; please aim your answers accordingly. :)

I'm planning to port the ISAAC CSPRNG algorithm to modern C++. I'm looking at Bob Jenkins' reference implementations: http://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/isaacafa.html

As I understand it, ISAAC has an internal state (`mm`) of ~259 `uint32`s, and it uses that state to produce a block of 256 `uint32` outputs (`randrsl`) at once. Producing that block of 256 outputs is the job of the `isaac()` function.

But in Jenkins' reference implementations there is also a function called `randinit()`. It looks like this function takes in a user-provided 256-word seed and initializes the `mm` array with a scrambling of the user-provided bits. The code to scramble these bits is 2x or 3x the length of the code for `isaac()` itself.

Apparently Jenkins' original paper on ISAAC claimed that it "has no bad initial states, not even the state of all zeros."[(secondhand source)](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/438.pdf)

The `randinit` function seems to pre-date by more than a decade [Aumasson's 2006 paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/438.pdf) that claims to identify *many* weak initial states; so I deduce that it is *not* the case that `randinit` was introduced in order to avoid those particular weak states.

So why go through all this extra scrambling — if Jenkins believed that there were no bad states, why did he not copy the user-provided seed directly into the `mm` array? Or, why not use ISAAC itself to do the scrambling, by copying the user-provided seed directly into `mm` and then discarding the first few thousand outputs of `isaac()`?

Comment: Can I assume you've seen http://burtleburtle.net/bob/cplus/isaac.hpp ?

Comment: @PaulUszak: Yes. That header file is crazy bizarre C++ (hence my desire for a clean modern version that models the `RandomUniformBitGenerator` concept); and it still doesn't help me understand the purpose of `randinit()`. In fact isaac.hpp adds a *second* public method, `srand()`, that *also* sets the initial state but *doesn't* do the shuffling that `randinit()` does!

Comment: Yeh, I got a D- in C++.  My Java implementation throws away the 1st round of output due to possible biases from poor seeding.  Could this be relevant to your last sentence?

Comment: @PaulUszak: Yes, I'm roughly familiar with the idea of "possible biases due to poor seeding". But if Jenkins believed that ISAAC had, quote, "no bad initial states", and if even *you* believed that just discarding a few blocks was good enough, why did Jenkins write such a massive and complicated `randinit` function?

Comment: Also, would someone mind tagging this question [csprng] [isaac] [seed]?